# My Tampermonkey script works but Tumblr refills the original information

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tumblr, tampermonkey

I'm working on a script to remove certain pre-loaded values in my tumblr blog when I share something.

What it does right now is click on the settings icon [image]

Then it removes the content source:

[image]

**The problem is** that after running the script, and submitting the post, the Content source is still appearing... seems Tumblr detects this and refills the value.

This doesn't happen if I do it manually.

Any clue on why this is happening?

I even put the setTimeout function and clicked on it to try to avoid it but it's not "saving" the information after.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         RemoveContent
// @namespace    http://www.myblog.com
// @version      0.1
// @description  Removes pre-loaded stuff
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.tumblr.com/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

document.querySelector(".post-settings").click();

waitForKeyElements (
    "#sourceUrl_input",
    changeContentInput
);

function changeContentInput () {
    setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('sourceUrl_input').click(); }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('sourceUrl_input').value = ""; }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('sourceUrl_input').click(); }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I'm using the tumblr bookmarklet on this example.

Comment: Instead of using Javascript, can not you add some custom CSS to hide the element?

Comment: 1. Use different values for timeouts, now they fire all at the same time one after another without intermediate delay. 2. Maybe the inputfield remembers its value only when it loses the input focus. Try `.blur()` instead of the last `.click()`.